# How to call a function while odoo loading

Tags: python, odoo

I'm working in odoo I have problem, the issue is I want a load or call the function while some view trigger

This is my view XML

```
 <page string="Current Allocated" id="curent_book_id">
                          <field name='book_transactions_id' domain="[('name', '=', 'Odoo Basics')]">
                            <tree>
                              <!-- <field name="code">self.check_date()</field> -->
                              <field name="auto_date_check" invisible="1" />
                              <field name='from_date'/>
                              <field name='end_date'/>
                              <field name='students_id'/>
                            </tree>
                           </field>

                       </page>
```

And model code:

```
    from_date = fields.Date(string='From Date',default=datetime.today())
    current_status = fields.Boolean(default=True)
    end_date = fields.Date(string='End Date')
    books_id = fields.Many2many('library.books', ondelete='cascade', string="Book Name")
    students_id = fields.Many2many('library.student',string='Student RollNo')
    auto_date_check = fields.Char(compute='check_date', store=False)

    @api.onchange('auto_date_check')
    def check_date(self):

        return {
                'warning': {
                            'title': "Something bad happened",
                            'message': "It was very bad indeed",
                            }`enter code here`
                }
```

Comment: This question is quite absurd and bad formulated. Doing that makes no sense per se. You should explain instead what you want to achieve, not how you want to achieve it, because chances are that you are not searching in the proper place.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following possibilities:

If you are trying to execute a method before creating a Record, then use "`default_get()`" method, which will be first method to execute for every New record creation.

Or

If you are trying to execute method when everytime view is loaded, then ensure `Compute method` which will compute the value for a field every time you load a view. However if the compute field is stored to database, then it will be triggered only at the time of creation or update/writing to that record

Or

If you are trying to execute method, at launch of Odoo server, then use "**init**()" method in your Object to perform your task.

[Reference Link](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/v10-how-to-call-a-model-method-when-view-is-loaded-or-at-least-when-odoo-server-is-launched-117693)